# Why is my CIFS share showing the same files multiple times?

Tags: debian, zfs, cifs

I have a Debian backup server running the FreeBSD kernel and a ZFS filesystem on which I store backups, using ZFS's snapshot and compression technologies. The Debian server uses `rsync` to pull files from multiple other servers via a cron job. This process works great.

I then use CIFS to share the backups back to the original servers, so I can easily browse them and restore files from each server. However, when I use `ls` on the servers to look at the contents of certain directories on the backup share (mounted via CIFS) I see the same exact files listed multiple times. Many, many times in fact:

```
[root@webserver01 public_html]# ls -li /backup/scripts/|less
total 663621
57872359 drwxr-xr-x  4 root root      0 Apr  3 21:40 ./
       2 drwxr-xr-x 20 root root      0 Mar 24 18:20 ../
57872880 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   6494 Dec 16  2008 AcctLock.pm
57873180 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      7 Mar 15 15:21 adddns -> add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
57872571 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns*
```

But on the debian backup server, it looks fine:

```
root@timestandstill:/# ls -l /backups/myvenue/scripts/|less
total 1893
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6494 Dec 16  2008 AcctLock.pm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Mar 15 15:21 adddns -> add_dns
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2010 Nov  8 20:55 add_dns
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   5797 Nov  8 20:55 addfpmail
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   1949 Nov  8 20:55 addpop
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    490 Oct 10  2007 addservlets
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     53 Mar 10  2008 adduser
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    305 Mar 23  2006 admin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   3926 Nov  8 20:55 after_perl_upgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    654 Mar 23  2006 anonuser.patch
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2961 Nov  8 20:55 apachelimits
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   1014 Sep 23  2010 apacheloadcheck
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     99 Mar 23  2006 aquota.user_emptyfs.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3023 Nov  8 20:55 archive_sync_zones
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   1109 Nov  8 20:55 autorepair
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   5167 Nov  8 20:55 bandminup
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   1540 Nov  8 20:55 biglogcheck
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    252 Mar 23  2006 bitstest
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2224 Nov  8 20:55 bsdbindfix
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2479 Nov  8 20:55 bsdcryptoinstall
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   3003 Nov  8 20:55 bsdi386compatinstall
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    430 Nov  8 20:55 bsdldconfig
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2363 Nov  8 20:55 bsdpkgpingtest
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    452 Dec 16  2008 buildbsdexpect
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2766 Nov  8 20:55 builddovecotconf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   5298 Nov  8 20:55 buildeximconf
```

What could be causing this and how can I resolve it? I'm not tied to CIFS, so if there's a better technology I am open to it. I was using NFS before when the backup server was Open Solaris, but it seems Debian doesn't support NFS when using the FreeBSD kernel...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're experiencing [Samba bug 4715](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4715), reported as [Debian bug #612503](http://bugs.debian.org/612503). Currently the recommended fix is to add `directory name cache size = 0` under the global section in `smb.conf`.