# CIFS getting mounted multiple times

Tags: linux, samba, mount, cifs

I mount the cifs export onto my server using this :

```
mount -t cifs -o rw,noperm,nounix,sec=ntlmssp,credentials=/root/.cifsauth,vers=2.1 //10.151.26.10/MyServer/MyMount /mnt/cifs
```

This results in at least fs getting mounted at least 3 times

```
//10.151.26.10/MyServer/MyMount
                     cifs    10T  5.5T  4.6T  55% /mnt/cifs
//10.151.26.10/MyServer/MyMount
                     cifs    10T  5.5T  4.6T  55% /mnt/cifs
//10.151.26.10/MyServer/MyMount
                     cifs    10T  5.5T  4.6T  55% /mnt/cifs

[root@MyMount samba]# uname -a
Linux MyMount 2.6.32-754.30.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 10 11:14:37 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Also , on an another vm running
Linux  2.6.18-238.19.1.el5 #1 SMP Fri Jul 15 07:31:24 EDT 2011 x86_64       x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
[root@DRSPRDDB01 ~]# mount -t cifs -o rw,noperm,nounix,sec=ntlmv2i,credentials=/var/lib/pgsql/.smbcredentials1 //eveotspcifs01/MyServer/MyMount /mnt/cifs
```

This also mounts at least 3 times

```
//eveotspcifs01/MyServer/MyMount
              cifs      11T   6.1T   5.0T  55% /mnt/cifs
//10.151.26.10/MyServer/MyMount
              cifs      11T   6.1T   5.0T  55% /mnt/cifs
```

Another observation is that its unmounted itself after some time
I know the OS are EOL , i cannot connect it to internet and update.
i did refer this thread and added entry to smb.conf , it didn't helped.
[Why is my CIFS share showing the same files multiple times?](https://serverfault.com/questions/255465/why-is-my-cifs-share-showing-the-same-files-multiple-times)

dmesg does show this messgae , but this seems like a warning message :
er mounting with the "noserverino" option to silence this message.
CIFS VFS: Autodisabling the use of server inode numbers on \10.151.26.10\MyServer. This server doesn't seem to support them properly. Hardlinks will not be recognized on this mount. Consider mounting with the "noserverino" option to silence this message.

Comment: You seem to be running a pretty ancient version of CentOS that has reached its end of life long ago. Try a supported release.